# Is this can cause a crash at any situation - copying the void buffer to the unsigned char?

Tags: c, linux

In one of the place in my project, the crash is happening at `memcpy()`. I analyzed the coredump and found that the pointer seems to be OK. The scenario is that the void buffer is the src and the char `buf[8]` is the destination. Can copying the `void *` to `char *` can cause crash at any situation?

I have tried to reproduce the snippet here, but I didn't get any crash in the PC.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void  main()
{

 void *buff  = "Hero";

 unsigned char buffer[5];

 memcpy(buffer,buff,5);

 printf("The value of buffer is %s\r\n", buffer);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that buff size is always corret ? try to reduce "Hero" to "He" and keep code as it is

Comment: Well, this question is not about size but about copying void * to unsigned char *.  It's obvious to me that the size needs to be changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't included `string.h` and are ignoring the warning that `memcpy` hasn't been defined. This means that the args will be treated as `int`s, and if `int` and pointers are different sizes on your machine/compiler then the code will crash.

Comment: If I could upvote twice..., does this happen to you? do you compile your programs without warnings?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few minor problems:

- `void main()` should be `int main()`
- you need a `return 0;` at the end of `main()`
- `void * buffer` should really be `const void * buffer` or better yet `const char * buffer` (since it's pointing at a string literal)
- `#include "stdio.h"` should be `#include <stdio.h>`

and one potentially major problem:

- you need to add `#include <string.h>` - omitting this may well result in a crash on a system where `int`s and pointers are different sizes (e.g. 32 bit `int`s and 64 bit pointers)

Note that you should always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) - that way the compiler will catch simple mistakes such as the above. It's also a good idea to require function prototypes - then your code wouldn't even compile since the missing prototype for `memset` would result in a compile error.

Comment: @PaulR Reason for void * buffer be declared as a constant?

Comment: @felipeek: answer updated - it's pointing at a string literal, which is non-modifiable.

Comment: @felipeek a reason why declaring a `void *` pointer constant would be wrong?

Comment: @iharob No reason. I was just curious

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const char *buffer`?

Comment: @unwind: well yes, that would be preferable and more idiomatic, but there's nothing inherently *wrong* with using a void pointer here - I'll add a note to the answer though.

Answer (score -2):

It will not crash. It is working fine. But you have to include the header `string.h`.